# Error log folder location and OLA's SQL maintenance solution

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

Looking at one of our dev sql servers, it has a -e startup parameter to define the error log folder at this location : E:\DATA\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG.  However, only E:\DATA\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL exists on disk.  I can see Ola's SQL maintenance output files on disk at E:\DATA\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log

Who / what is responsible for creating the error log folder as defined by the -e startup parameter?

Does OLA's maintenance solution have a fallback if it can't find the log folder defined with -E startup parameter?

Answer (score 0):

All the code is on github
There is quite a lot of it now
[github link](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/blob/master/MaintenanceSolution.sql)

```
IF @Version >= 11
  BEGIN
    SELECT @LogDirectory = [path]
    FROM sys.dm_os_server_diagnostics_log_configurations
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT @LogDirectory = LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName') AS nvarchar(max)),LEN(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName') AS nvarchar(max))) - CHARINDEX('\',REVERSE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ErrorLogFileName') AS nvarchar(max)))))
END
```